# Get GitLab Issue Service Desk Email via API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I'm creating a separate app for users to visualize GitLab issues without needing access to GitLab. We are using `python-gitlab` to retrieve the issue data for display on this separate site. Users will create new issues by clicking a button that opens up an email configured with the project's Service Desk email.

This all works great so far. BUT, we need to get the issue-specific email address in order to provide an option for users to add a comment via this separate app. According to the documentation, the issue email address is readily available on the issue itself -- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#copy-issue-email-address.

Is there a way to retrieve this issue-specific email via the GitLab API?

Answer (score 0):

This information is available in the `GET` request of a project. The information on how to do this is on the [API Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html).

If the `service_desk_enabled` key is `true`, there will be an email address in the `service_desk_address` key. This will reflect the value in the settings of the project.

If you haven't changed any defaults, this looks like the email address is made up of:

- "contact-project+"
- project group name + "-"
- project name + "-"
- Project ID + "-"
- "issue-@incoming.gitlab.com"

That way, if it's not available in the request but the setting is enabled, you should be able to build it